# How can I get the data type from an HTTP response from a Nodejs server in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm creating an Angular application connected to a Nodejs backend server. The Nodejs server response can be an array or Json object. I have to catch the correct data type according to the server response.

This is my Angular service code.
Note that my HttpClient functions return Json objects. Is there any function that returns any type of data?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

import { City } from '../models/City';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CityService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  API_URI = 'http://localhost:5000'

  getCities() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/City`);
  }
  
  getCity(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/City/${id}`);
  }

  deleteCity(id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.API_URI}/City/${id}`);
  }

  saveCity(city: City) { 
    return this.http.post(`${this.API_URI}/City`, city);
  }

  updateCity(id: string|number|undefined, updatedCity: City): Observable<City> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.API_URI}/City/${id}`, updatedCity);
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: An http response contains [headers](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) in those headers you can get the `content-type` header that the server sent.

Comment: If you are just trying to test if the return data is an `array` or an `object`, you can do `if(Array.isArray(someData)) {/*I'm an array*/} else {/*I'm an object*/}`

Comment: but the problem is that those get(), post(), delete() and put() functions are returning Json objects by their definition. I need a way to get the body response in its corresponding datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the returned type and transform the response in a `map` operator, you can then handle it accordingly in your `subscribe`

```
getCities() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/City`).pipe(
       map( body => {
            return {
                isArray: Array.isArray(body),
                data: body
            }
       })
    )
  }
```

It's strange behavior for an API to return either an array or object (usually it's always one or the other). I suspect there may be something missing in your understanding/processing of the response, but I could be wrong

Comment: I think it was my mistake. I didn't realize I could send those server responses parsed into a single datatype. Thank u so much!